# What is the best practices to save data in private AWS s3 and it's url to mongodb and only authrized user can access the data url?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm a new developer trying to figure out the best practices of storing data in AWS s3.
I'm trying to create a website where users can upload their videos or pictures and this will be only accessible to them. If they share the video or picture with another user only then the other user can have read access to it.

So, what I'm planning to do is this,
I want to allow users to upload their data through node js server and nodejs will handle the data uploading in s3 bucket. But here's the main question, How can I get the url of that private object and save to mongodb database. And how can I put the authentication method to the object url to only accessible to the user who put that object or whoever he shared that object to?

Comment: Take a look at cloud front signed urls - these are temp URLs you dynamically generate with restrictions(ttl, source ip, date ranges etc) from your node app so you can use your existing user/auth system to decide who can see what url. In this setup your S3 bucket is kept private(best practice) but allows cloudfront access, and the  data goes via a CDN to your end users(performance/cost advantage). If you know the bucket name, region and objects key uploaded you can work out the URL - check the docs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thought about using this method and I might end up using this. If I do it this way then I'll have to take the object key and save to mongodb database. And whenever a user request for his content, I'll have to loop through all the content and get all the presigned url for all the content he has. Is this a best practice? Or is there any other method I can work with?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: These technologies will do what you require, but the "best" option depends on your use cases. Media being shared with a few users is very different to thousands or millions of users, and users having a few media items verses many and how far they are shared will also impact you design. Your mongo collections structure is critical - how you index and query them has a big impact on performance/scalability. I dont have an answer, but i suggest you, think about your apps purpose and use cases/expected volumes and then ask more specific questions.

Comment: Thanks MisterSmith. I'm a bit curious to know, if you don't mind can you share your knowledge about the use cases  of data storage of big companies. How they struct their databases and storages for this kind of use cases?